# Conditional Filtering in SQL Server Based on Multiple Parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2019

In my SQL Server report, I need to filter data based on multiple parameters. Specifically, I want to apply different conditions in the WHERE clause depending on the value of one parameter and then check another parameter to determine the filtering logic.

For instance, I want to retrieve data where Parameter1 matches a certain value and then based on that, evaluate Parameter2 to execute one set of conditions if it meets a criterion, or another set of conditions if it doesn't.

```
Where 
    case when @Parameter1 = 'value'  then
        ColumnName = @Parameter2
    when case when @Parameter1 = 'value2' then
        ColumnName = @Parameter2
    when case when @Parameter1 = 'value3' then
        ColumnName = @Parameter2
    when case when @Parameter1 = 'value4' then
        ColumnName = @Parameter2
```

Could someone provide guidance on how to structure the WHERE clause to accommodate these conditional filters in SQL Server?

Comment: `where case when @Parameter1 = 'X' and columnX = @Parameter2 then 1 when @Parameter1 = 'Y' and columnY = @Parameter2 then 1 ... end = 1`

Comment: Don't use such code in the first place because it results in bad execution plans. Neither SSRS nor any other reporting engines require such catch-all queries. This is a very strong smell. There's no IF in WHERE, and CASE is an expression - it returns a value that must be compared to something. The server won't recompile the query every time though, which means it will reuse the execution plan created for the *first* execution, whether it's appropriate or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to dynamically filter your SQL query based on different conditions of `@Parameter1`. You can use a combination of `CASE` statements and boolean logic in your `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTableName
WHERE 
    CASE 
        WHEN @Parameter1 = 'value' AND ColumnName = @Parameter2 THEN 1
        WHEN @Parameter1 = 'value2' AND ColumnName = @Parameter2 THEN 1
        WHEN @Parameter1 = 'value3' AND ColumnName = @Parameter2 THEN 1
        WHEN @Parameter1 = 'value4' AND ColumnName = @Parameter2 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END = 1
```

Also you can use `OR` conditions to check different values of `@Parameter1` and filter rows based on the condition specified in `ColumnName = @Parameter2`.

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTableName
WHERE 
    (@Parameter1 = 'value' AND ColumnName = @Parameter2)
    OR (@Parameter1 = 'value2' AND ColumnName = @Parameter2)
    OR (@Parameter1 = 'value3' AND ColumnName = @Parameter2)
    OR (@Parameter1 = 'value4' AND ColumnName = @Parameter2)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do it like below

```
Where ColumnName =
 case
 when @Parameter1 = 'value'  and @Parameter2= 'val' then  'somevalue'
 when @Parameter1 = 'value1'  and @Parameter2= 'val1' then'somevalue1'
 when @Parameter1 = 'value2'  and @Parameter2= 'val2' then  'somevalue2'
 ELSE 'somevalue3'
END
```